# Am I using requireJS wrong, or is the library I downloaded severely bugged?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, static-libraries, require

I'm trying to use a JS library ([this](https://github.com/agilemd/logica)) which makes use of the `require` function. To use it, I understand I have some options, as elaborated on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined). So I go with requireJS and I link to it and the library I want to use as such in my html file.

```
<script src="requirejs/reqjs.js"></script>
<script src="LIBRARY_I_WANT_TO_USE/index.js"></script>
```

the first line of index.js looks like this

```
var foo = require('PATH')
```

For that line, the console outputs this error:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "PATH" has not been loaded yet for
>   context: _. Use require([])

So I find [this](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded) at requirejs.org:

> This occurs when there is a require('name') call, but the 'name' module has not been loaded yet.

It goes on to suggest ways to resolve the problem. But I hesitate to start modifying the code of the library I just downloaded. Now my question is,

**Is the library I downloaded bugged, or am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: you are using requireJS wrong, and the library is bugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library is written using CommonJS modules, not AMD modules (which is what RequireJS implements).

You need to use browserify to bundle it into a single file that can load in the browser.